# How to run windows Application Visual Studio 2012 to Pocket PC ?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, frameworks, pocketpc

When i try to copy the application to pocket pc . The pocket PC asking for .NET Frame work 4.0 . visual studio 2012 dont have setup deployment for cab files..

any suggestion to run my application in Pocket PC . Thank you

Comment: I think you're going to need to downgrade to .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You can easily download the Framework from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718)